# Casting to types that are know only at Runtime by their string names. C#

Tags: string, types, casting

I've got a problem here. (C#)

There's a collection in another assembly (I cannot change it) that takes a string as parameter and returns an object.

Like:

```
object Value = ThatCollection.GetValue("ParameterName");
```

The problem is, for each parameter string, it returns a DIFFERENT type as object.
What I want is to cast those objects to their respective types, knowing the types only at runtime by their string names.

I need to do some operations with those returned values. 
And for that I need to cast them properly in order to access their members and so.

Limitations:

- I cannot use "dynamic" since my code needs to be done in an older framework: 3.5 (because of interop issues).
- I need to do operations with MANY returned values of different types (no common interfaces nor base classes, except "object", of course)
- All I have is a table (containing string values) correlating the parameter names with their returned types.
- Yes, I could transform that table into a biiig "switch" statement, not very nice, don't want that.

Any hints??

Answer (score 0):

You want to look into reflection, something like the following should work to cast an object to type T. Set up a simple cast method:

```
    public static T CastToType<T>(object o)
    {
        return (T)o;
    }
```

Invoke this using reflection:

```
    Type t = Type.GetType(stringName)
    MethodInfo castTypeMethod = this.GetType().GetMethod("CastToType").MakeGenericMethod(t);
    object castedObject = castTypeMethod .Invoke(null, new object[] { obj });
```

Comment: That's interesting to learn. But since the result is still "object", I'm stuck at the same point. And the object I need to cast already is of the type I want, but as object. I'm trying to figure out a way to explicit that type, and I believe I cannot escape the "switch".

Comment: Can I get operators (not just methods) via reflection?

Comment: I don't think there is a good way to do what you want without the switch, at some point you need to know the type you are dealing with to interact with it.